# Unable to retrieve the values added in the hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

This code is not giving me data when i try to retrieve data second time.

1. I enter domain name and ip address
2. again i enter DN and Ip
3. I search for 1st ip its gives correct result.
4. When i search for 2nd ip it says domain name not found

I am not sure why my loop is not giving correct result?
I can see that the data is available it enters the if section verified but does not return the data,it goes to the the else section and prints that no data is available.

```
 //Main class
{
     System.out.println("1. Add DNS details");
     System.out.println("2. Find matching Domain Name");
     System.out.println("3. Exit");
     System.out.println("Enter your choice");

    //After entering the choice 
    System.out.println("Enter the IP address to find the domain name");
    ip = sc.nextLine();
    DomainName = dBO.findDomainName(ip);
}

    //FindDomainname.java class
    public String findDomainName(String ipAddress) {
        
      String domain=null;
        
        if(domainMap.isEmpty()){
        return domain;
        }
        else
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : domainMap.entrySet()) {
            String k = entry.getKey();
            String v = entry.getValue(); 
            
            if (ipAddress.equals(v)) {
                domain = k;                 
            }
            else
            {
                domain = "No matching domain name found";
                
            }
     }    
    
    return domain;
}
```

Comment: do you have any `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, etc. before the call to `sc.nextLine()`?

Comment: You don't need to check if the map is empty explicitly. The loop does the same for an empty map as the explicit check does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Stream solution. Your error was not breaking out of the loop when a match was found.

```
public String findDomainName(String ipAddress) {
    return domainMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(ipAddress))
        .findAny().orElse(domainMap.isEmpty() ? null
                          : "No matching domain name found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to break out of the for loop as soon as you find the entry, otherwise it will move on the the next entry in the map and that entry may not match. add break statement like so:

```
if (ipAddress.equals(v)) {                
    domain = k;  
    break;               
}
```